# Knockout JS - fetching data from server and rebinding - front-end performance problems

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a demo [application](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5898/) in which I have an array where all elements are observables. In this app I have a function that simulates a call from a server - getting the same array that is bound to the list, but with one item changed. This is the way I have implemented it:

```
this.serverDataSimulation=function(){
   aArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 0)].name=Math.floor((Math.random() 
* 2000) + 1000);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(aArray, this.allItems);
}
```

aArray is the simulation of data fetched from the server and I am binding it to the list with ko.mapping. The problem is that this way the whole list gets rerendered, instead of only updating the one item. I still want all the elements of the array to be observables after the rebinding as well as before rebinding. Is there any way to fix this or a better implementation?

Comment: You could read the section **Uniquely identifying objects using “keys”** in this link:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html.  I'm not sure, but perhaps in your observable array only changes the element you changed in the `aArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.serverDataSimulation=function(){
  var selectedItem = this.allItems()[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 0)];
  selectedItem.name(Math.floor((Math.random() * 2000) + 1000));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jorgelig/GSvnh/5897/

Comment: Sorrry, but the code you are suggesting is just changing the name of a random item and has nothing to do with the array that is "returned by a server".